# I sent tokens to the token contract

Tags: tokens, recovery

I transfered tokens with Ethereum chain to the token address and I can't get it back. It will be possible to recover them when ERC223 is implemented? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "when ERC223 is implemented"?

Comment: ERC223 is a new version that avoid this problem so I wonder if is implemented in a near future I would be able to recover them.

Comment: I know what ERC-223 is. The question is what do you mean by "implementing it"? You mean the entire industry to switch to using ERC-223? Only a portion (say, 10%)? Only the centralized exchanges (e.g. Binance)?

Or do you mean that the token contract that you used to be ported to ERC-223? If this is what you mean, the answer is "not possible", unless the token contract is upgradeable.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid not.

I assume you sent tokens to the "Contract address?"

It will never be possible to take/recover tokens from an address if you don't have a private key to the said address. That is how blockchain architecture works at its core.

That said, maybe the contract you sent your tokens to was supposed to exchange your tokens for some other ones?? If that is the case, you should be safe and your "new" tokens are at your address, you might just not see them (a problem with wallet setting for Metamask, TrustWallet etc)

EDIT:

But as far as I can see you sent 1794 nICE tokens to the contract address.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with my tokens change for other one's. I contact them and they told me is nothing they can do.

Comment: Sometimes you are required to send ETH or tokens to a contract address and in turn, you get other tokens (smart contract exchanges them for you). So I thought that might be the case here too. But I guess not.

Where did you send your tokens, at what address?

Comment: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1ebacb447e9a1f5775e21409eed7ccb8c085f4d2f798fbf315d5955c8feaff16

Comment: Ah, so you sent your tokens there to stake them?

Comment: Yes. I already staked and I send them to the token address. My tokens are there but they told me is no way to get it back which is unbelievable.

Comment: Tokens was already stacked and I was trying to unstake them and I send it to the token address. About the private key of the contract it should be mine as I was the owner, correct? Where I can find it?

Comment: You own the contract to which you sent the tokens? You deployed the contract?

Comment: What do you mean with deployed the contract. I stacked mi Ice into nIce using the web app of the token owner: https://app.popsicle.finance/nICE/

Comment: Can somebody confirm if this contract has transfer sending option available? 0xff3ac80c1caa08cbd43a7e90d20c398d54c7342f